# ZoneAwareError when importing InfiniteScrollModule

Tags: angular

When I import the InfiniteScrollModule from 'angular2-infinite-scroll'  to my module a ZoneAwareError shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you import it ? Do you follow the installation instructions correctly ?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'angular2-infinite-scroll';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app';

@NgModule({
  imports:[ BrowserModule, InfiniteScrollModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And then in your component (part of the module before) template you just add

```
<div class="search-results"
            infinite-scroll
            [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
            [infiniteScrollThrottle]="300"
            (scrolled)="thisIsYourFunction()">
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please add some code snippet of how you import it ? which angular version are you working on ?